# nuxt3 running on node server 301 redirects

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, nuxtjs3

I have a nuxt3 site running on a node server. How do I go about implementing 301 redirects? Ordinarily I would implement with apache or nginx, but it does not seem like we have apache or nginx running on the server?